# Best way to manage Mongoose Relationship

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, relationship, mongoose-schema

I have 3 models `model1`  `model2`  `model3`, it schema looks like this -

```
const model1Schema = new Schema ({
    //dummy data
    _model2SchemaAssociated: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ref:'model2'}],
    _model3SchemaAssociated: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ref:'model3'}]
});


const model2Schema = new Schema ({
    //dummy data

    _model1SchemaAssociated: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ref:'model1'}],
    _model3SchemaAssociated: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ref:'model3'}]
});

const model3Schema = new Schema ({
    //dummy data

    _model1SchemaAssociated: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ref:'model1'}],
    _model2SchemaAssociated: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ref:'model2'}]
});
```

whenever new document is added to any of the above models, i want to update the `associatedSchemas`.

**My Solution**
Find the other 2 models whenever any of the schema is saved. and update the current schema

But I feel this as a in-efficient operation.

Is there any better way to solve this?